# "No space left on device" on Raspberry Pi 3 used as NAS

Tags: disk-usage

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 used as NAS with a USB LUKS encrypted drive and SMB. When I try to copy I get:

```
$ cp -r /media/pi/Backup/Backups/_altii/Daniel/ /media/pi/share/
cp: eroare la scrierea '/media/pi/share/Daniel/poze 2012-27 aprilie 2021/1614357450431.JPG': No space left on device
```

which in English says `cp: error writing '/media/pi/share/Daniel/poze 2012-27 aprilie 2021/1614357450431.JPG': No space left on device`

`df -h` shows 720GB left:

```
$ df -h /dev/dm-0
Sistem de fișiere                                     Dimens Utilizat Liber  Uz% Montat pe
/dev/mapper/luks-b8ddc005-ebe8-4219-8ae4-6eae54159a6b   1,8T     978G  720G  58% /media/pi/Backup
```

`du -sh` shows zero:

```
$ du -sh /dev/dm-0
0   /dev/dm-0
```

There are free inodes:

```
$ df -i /dev/dm-0
Sistem de fișiere                                       Inoduri IUtilizat    ILiber IUz% Montat pe
/dev/mapper/luks-b8ddc005-ebe8-4219-8ae4-6eae54159a6b 119046144   2562741 116483403   3% /media/pi/Backup
```

And there are not open deleted files:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/share $ lsof | grep deleted
pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/share $ 
pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/share $ lsof /dev/dm-0 | grep deleted
pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/share $
```

Comment: Please state the complete cp command - not just the error message. Note, there is no ";;;" location.

Comment: I updated the cp with actual command output (in Romanian and English translation)

Comment: The `df` output looks to be for a different location (`/media/pi/Backup`) then where you are attempting to copy data (`/media/pi/share/`).  Please show the information for the filesystem at `/media/pi/share/`.